# Signals do not work after registering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-signals

So far I have `signals.py`  with following content:

```
    from django.db.models.signals import post_delete, post_save
    from django.core.signals import request_finished
    from django.dispatch import receiver
    from students.models import Student


    @receiver(post_save, sender=Student)
    def track_saved_objects(sender, **kwargs):
        print 'i am here'
        new_instance = kwargs['instance']
        print new_instance

    @receiver(request_finished)
    def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
        print("Request finished!")
```

And I can not get why signals do not register and nothing happening with this code, nothing printed that means my signals are inactive
In docs I've found something about `AppConfig.ready()` but still can not get where else should I register my signals

Comment: Try to put them in `students.models`

Comment: @Aamir, I don't think that is a good idea, see the section "Where should this code live?" in the documentation about signals.

Comment: @e-nouri yes you are right if Django version is 1.7, I forgot about the Django version as OP hasn't mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As e-nouri said in the comments, this information is in the docs. If you scroll down from the [Connecting Receiver Functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions) section to the "Where should this code live?" note, you'll see they should live in the `AppConfig` as you alluded to in your question.

In your application, you'll need to create an apps.py file if you don't have one created already. In it you'll define the config for your app. Here's an example that includes the signals registration.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ExampleAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'example'
    verbose_name = "Example Application"

    def ready(self):
        # To avoid putting the signals code in the __init__.py file or
        # models.py file, we import the signals module here.
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions
        from example import signals
```